# Moved temporaly 302 to localhost

Tags: networking

I can't connect to the following url: https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/
this is the trace i see in chrome network inspector
[chrome inspector 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73p4j.png)

[chrome inspector 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWvEY.png)

and this is the traceroute:
[Traceroute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAVJL.png)

After a while the page loads well. But after a few minutes or seconds the same thing happens again. My pc has no proxy configured or VPN.

What can happen?

Comment: Try : (1) disable your antivirus and firewall, (2) Enter Chrome Incognito mode, (3) another browser.

Comment: I have tried all 3 things without success. When it works, it only does a few minutes.

Comment: Why are you getting references to localhost? You are using the Internet after all. If it happens on another browser, this cannot be an installed extension. Might be something you have installed on the computer.

Answer (score -1):

A year old, but for any that find themselves here like I did:

When Bet365 detects you are using an industry grade connection, like a VPN or proxy or VPS, etc, their serverside redirects you to localhost to, in effect, null route you.